# Text is out of my descriptive diagram

Tags: smartdiagram

I'm using a descriptive diagram to display some equations, but I've faced a trouble when I make a longer equation, my text goes out of the description box, so my question is how to make the text start from the left corner of my descriptive box item or in generally how to fit it with the item box:

[image]

```
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{center}
   \smartdiagramset{
   description title font = \scriptsize,
   descriptive items y sep =  2cm,
   description title text width=2cm,
   description title width= 2cm,
   description width=8cm,
    description text width=4cm
}
      \smartdiagramanimated[descriptive diagram]{
      {  title1,
      { \begin{eqnarray*}
            my equation
    \end{eqnarray*}}},
  {  { title2},
      { \begin{eqnarray*}
    my equation2
 \end{eqnarray*}}},
  {  {title3},
{\begin{eqnarray*}
 equation 3
  \end{eqnarray*}}}} 
 \end{center}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: can you show some code to go with you image?

Comment: sorry, I thought it was a known example about the descriptive diagram, I've made update, please take a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `description text width` was too small for the equation. Because it was much smaller than the `description text`, it was no longer centred but overflowed on the right. Make it the same width:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}
    \begin{center}
   \smartdiagramset{
   description title font = \scriptsize,
   descriptive items y sep =  2cm,
   description title text width=2cm,
   description title width= 2cm,
   description width=8cm,
    description text width=8cm
}
      \smartdiagramanimated[descriptive diagram]{
      {  title1,
      { \begin{align*}
            f(x) &= a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j\\
            f(x) &= a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j
    \end{align*}}},
  {  { title2},
      { \begin{align*}
    my equation2
 \end{align*}}},
  {  {title3},
{\begin{align*}
 equation 3
  \end{align*}}}} 
 \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(I would not use `eqnarray`, something like `align` might be better)

Comment: Thank you for your solution but I already handled it with \hspace :) but I'll just give you my thanks for taking your time to help me